# Accessing props in separate function in a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple Parent Functional Component (App.js) and a child Functional component (counters.jsx), I want to pass a signal/prop from child to parent. I want to send the props as an argument to another function in my child component. I can easily trigger parent function by **onClick={props.parentCallback}**. but if I send the same props as an argument to another function in child component, I get the error **"Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions"**

```
//This is parent Component, App.js
    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App"> 
          <Counters parentCallback = {handleCallback}/>      
        </div>
      );
    }

const handleCallback = () => {
  console.log("CALLED FRM CHILD");
}

 //This is Child Component- Counters.jsx   
      
    function Counters (props) {
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={ ()=> parentHandler(props) }>CALL PARENT</button><hr/>
          {//onClick={props.parentCallback} - This works well}
        </div>
      );
    };
function parentHandler (props) {
      props.parentCallback; // This line throws the aforementioned error 
      }
```

Comment: You're not calling the function, it should read `props.parentCallback()`

Comment: Maybe just add parenthesis? `props.parentCallback()`

Comment: why shoud I use parenthesis? The "parentCallback" is just a prop, not a function, though it holds a function, does that make it another function? if its so, why this works without parenthesis- onClick={props.parentCallback}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank u for ur answer guys, but none of the answer is exactly what I wanted. Finally, I got the answer myself as it is:

**Do you need the function to run now?**

Then add the () to execute it

**Do you need to function to be referenced so it is called later?**

Do not add the ().

**More example:**

onClick=parentCallback() means call "parentCallback() ASAP, and set its return value to onClick".

On the other hand, onClick=parentCallback means "onClick is an alias for parentCallback. If you call onClick(), you get the same results as calling parentCallback()"

I found it by googling "function call and function reference".

Answer (score 1):

You are just referencing the function. Not calling it. You can modify parentHandler function as

```
function parentHandler (props) {
  props.parentCallback()
  }
```

Comment: why shoud I use parenthesis? The "parentCallback" is just a prop, not a function, though it holds a function, does that make it another function?  if its so, why this works without parenthesis- onClick={props.parentCallback}.

Answer (score 1):

**no-unused-expressions** usually means that you evaluated a value but never used. This rule aims to eliminate unused expressions.
**For example** `if(true) 0`

In your case you are calling `props.parentCallback` without parenthesis, leaving unused. Either you add parenthesis after your function call like this `props.parentCallback()` or return some value at the end. By that your eslint error will disappear.

Also `onClick={props.parentCallback}` - This works well because you are just passing a reference of your function to the parent Component. But here `onClick={ ()=> parentHandler(props) }` you are creating a new inline function on each render.